# Validating that which can not be validated, how do we deal with robots exclusions?

Tags: discussion, link-validator

Many high profile sites have taken a "white-list" based approach to [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)

Examples are:

- [Github](https://github.com/robots.txt)
- [Facebook](https://facebook.com/robots.txt)
- [Delicious](http://delicious.com/robots.txt)

The result is that we are not **allowed** to automatically check that any external links to these sites are kosher.

The scale of the problem is fairly big, for example (for a sample of 5000 of the earliest links)

- 3.5% are uncrawlable due to robots exclusion.
- 5.8% are broken

---

How should we be dealing with these uncrawlable links?

Comment: What is the error code the excluded sites are returning?

Comment: @RobertHarvey the exclusion in robots bans us from checking the links ... there is no error.

Comment: How could that be?  If you try to hit the link, there has to be some sort of response code.

Comment: @waffles: Change your user-agent to Googlebot. Simple.

Comment: @RobertHarvey we hit robots.txt first, parse it, it tells us we are not allowed to check ANY links on the site, so we stop.

Comment: @TimManishEarth A WINNING suggestion :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Basically, it's a standard that you're expected to follow. You can sidestep it, of course--I don't think the system _forces_ you to parse robots.txt

Comment: @TimManishEarth: That's what I think you should do.  It's not like we're crawling the entire site, or even a substantial part of it.  Nor are we scraping for email addresses.  Google will respect it, of course, because they must crawl the entire site, or at least that part that's publicly visible.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: (Source:Wikipedia) The Robot Exclusion Standard, also known as the Robots Exclusion Protocol or robots.txt protocol, is a convention to prevent **cooperating** web crawlers and other web robots from accessing all or part of a website which is otherwise publicly viewable.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yeah, me too. We don't exactly _crawl_ the web page, we just point-and-shoot.

Comment: That's right.  If our intention was to act like any other web crawler, then maybe we should be treated like one.  But this could be done very gently, with a lot of throttling, and extremely low traffic.  It will not substantially impact anyone.

Comment: For context I am performing a throttled `HEAD` request to each link, respecting crawl delay and all.

Comment: You're not really crawling if you're just poking Abe Vigoda

Comment: @waffles: If it's a `HEAD` request, then there's nothing to worry about. Any server load generated by our bot(not following robots.txt) will be millions of times smaller than the load generated by a crawler following robots.txt.

Comment: @TimManishEarth for the other record my requests for robots.txt are "compressed" ... but you know ... the long tail. Also, HEAD often still generates the same amount of server load.

Comment: So uh, maybe move this to webmasters as it's awfully not SO specific?

Comment: @KevinMontrose was thinking of cross posting there as well

Comment: Don't cross post, just migrate.  This discussion shouldn't be "hidden away" on meta; webmasters is the correct place for this.

Comment: @KevinMontrose both are correct places imho

Comment: It's correct here, but if you remove the implicit "we, Stack Exchange" it fits elsewhere and should go there as people looking for this information are unlikely to look on a meta site.

Answer (score 21):

Here's how we feel about it at GitHub, from [Aman Gupta](https://github.com/tmm1):

[image]

Normal crawlers wreak havoc on our servers, because they can find content that isn't actually commonly seen (i.e. a persistent crawler can walk an entire Git history by following parent links), and it blows any attempt at caching by filling the cache with bogus entries.

In this case, because you're not *crawling*, you're not quite the same as a robot - the worries we have about GoogleBot don't apply here.

Comment: What about abnormal bot that don't respect the robots.txt, because you are somehow pushing robots to not respect your robots.txt

Answer (score 14):

I would not worry about it for now. What you're doing isn't very much different than a user interface doing an AJAX check to validate a link to show a little green check mark next to it in a UI. Due to the same origin policy, those have to go through a proxy and checking robots.txt in that scenario would seem extremely silly.

For the long term, you *could* set up a proper bot (just like Googlebot) and send the corresponding user agent, give it time to circulate and *then* check robots.txt for exclusions, but I really think doing so is going *way* above and beyond what a good netizen should be doing. You aren't crawling or indexing, you're just sending a HEAD request to see the status of any given link, and you're doing it nicely. There's no *good* reason to make two requests instead of one initially, or deal with the complexity of caching a bunch of robots.txt files to avoid it.

Finally, I think *most* site owners would *want* Stack Overflow to make every effort to verify inbound links to their site, as the only alternative would be to remove those that can't be verified wholesale.

Answer (score 12):

Since robots.txt doesn't *force* us to follow it:

> The Robot Exclusion Standard, also known as the Robots Exclusion Protocol or robots.txt protocol, is a convention to prevent **cooperating** web **crawlers** and **other web robots** from accessing all or part of a website which is otherwise publicly viewable.

<sup>[(source)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)</sup>

Basically, you want to be the good-guy cooperating crawler, right? Well, we don't *crawl* links. Crawlers spread out through every link they get and basically end up parsing nearly the whole site. That's bad when a site has tons of links that don't *need* to be crawled.

On the other hand, we take a link, point, and shoot. There's no "crawling" involved--nothing that can spiral into bigtime server load if we hit a page with millions of links. That's pretty much why we have `robots.txt`-- to prevent the robots from <s>taking over the world</s> overloading the site.

Though, if you notice, there's the "other web robots" in the Wikipedia snippet. Not complying with `robots.txt` will mean that we are complying with the *intentions* of `robots.txt`, but not with the actual *rules*. Which is OK, since overly broad rules are meant to be broken. And, it's not really a "rule" per se--it's a "listen if you know what's good for you" thingy:

> Despite the use of the terms "allow" and "disallow", the protocol is **purely advisory**.

And, we're old enough to know what's good for us without having them tell us, right? ;-)

So just point-and-shoot. Don't even *fetch* robots.txt, it unecessarily increases server load a teensy bit. Though, as @Dennis suggested, you can consult robots.txt if you have a truckload of links on the same domain that you need to verify.

Comment: Well, with different highlighting, this becomes _is a convention to prevent cooperating web crawlers and other **web robots** from accessing all or **part of a website** which is otherwise publicly viewable._

Comment: one could argue that even hitting robots.txt for our context is a bad way to act ... especially if we only need to point and shoot at a "single" link

Comment: @waffles: If you hadn't mentioned it, I wouldn't have even thought of checking robots.txt.

Comment: @Dennis: I know.. Actually I'll add that.. Issue is, we're complying with the _motivation_ behind robots.txt, but not the _rules_ behind it.

Comment: @waffles: *Single* link sounds nice. But how many Facebook links are there?

Comment: @Dennis: _why_ do we have FB links on SO??

Comment: @Dennis: Relative to the total traffic on Facebook?  It's infinitesimally small.

Comment: @TimManishEarth: Nevermind. I misunderstood parts of the question. Unless there is a big amount of links on a single website that have to be verified, I agree that `robots.txt` shouldn't be consulted.

Comment: @Dennis: And even robots need to spend time on FB, don't they? ;-)

Comment: @TimManishEarth: I don't know. I never was a robot nor have I ever spent time on Facebook (sorted by likelihood to happen, decreasing).

Comment: @Dennis: Same here, actually  :P

Comment: @waffles I don't see anything wrong with just hitting a link to verify it exists, and I see no reason to consult robots.txt prior to doing it, even if you have a large amount of links to check on a single domain. Just stagger them appropriately and be done with it. Consulting robots.txt is in no way useful, as it will never give you explicit permission to do it. The alternate is removing any questionable link on SO that can't be verified, which I'm sure the domain owner would not want.