# Dead link hunter-killer

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, link-rot

Did a quick search for similar, sorry if I duped.

Feature suggest for any SE site:

- run a cron task...
- that checks all posted links for dead-ness...
- using methods suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65515/how-to-find-broken-links-on-a-website) or elsewhere
- if link is dead <s>strike it out</s> or similar
- (optional) notify poster of link
- (optional) if post/comment containing the dead link has 50% link chars (i.e. the post/comment is mostly the link), the flag for deletion

Comment: +1, but let's called it "dead link hunter" - giving a badge for being a hunter implies that you have plenty of kills...

Comment: I believe waffles was working on a built-in tool for this shortly before he left... pretty sure there was a Meta post somewhere... looking....

Comment: @PopularDemand [Does Stack Exchange crawl websites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130398)

Comment: Waffles left???  Sorry to hear that.

Comment: @PopularDemand I remember that too. It creates comments like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35453/funny-observation-about-experts-exchange-and-stack-overflow#comment366528_35453)

Comment: I haven't heard anything about the bot being deactivated, so I'd assume this is already taken care of...there's just no longer a `/review` route for posts that get comments.

Comment: @AdamRackis He's off to new adventures ([relevant blog post](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/06/14/leaving-stack-exchange))

Comment: In addition to Tim's link, see [Validating that which can not be validated, how do we deal with robots exclusions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132675/validating-that-which-can-not-be-validated-how-do-we-deal-with-robots-exclusion) and [How should we handle “conditionally” broken links?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132892/how-should-we-handle-conditionally-broken-links)

Comment: @AdamRackis well, he _claims_ to have moved on, but... his profile says "seen 1 hour ago."

Comment: @Popular Demand: He has left the company, but not the community :)

Comment: Suuuuuuure, @BoltClock'saUnicorn. You know he's still logging in when he thinks nobody's checking the logs, submitting little patches here and there....

Comment: A good feature for such a tool would be to check archive.org to see if there is archived content available there & replace the link with one to the archived content (perhaps with an appropriate flag). But what about dead links that come back to life? How ever a dead link is handled it ought to be checked for resurrection.

Comment: IMHO should be implemented the way _users_ mark the link as dead. After a number of such reports the author of the answer gets a notification with a request to update the link or find an alternative location. If no change for a certain period of time -> strike the link through